# Apache restricting access to a folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I copied a directory into `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dir-name`

Now when I start the server and go to `localhost/xampp/dir-name/index.php` only the raw html gets loaded without any css or js applied to it and the chrome console shows the follwing:

```
GET http://localhost/xampp/dir-name/css/normalize.css 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:13
GET http://localhost/xampp/dir-name/css/main.css 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:14
GET http://localhost/xampp/dir-name/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:16
GET http://localhost/xampp/dir-name/images/zoom.png 403 (Forbidden) 

// Many more like that.
```

Comment: Check your apache logs.

Comment: What is that? Can you spoon it please

Comment: Open up your XAMPP Control Panel, click logs, check the error.log and php_error.log files for errors.

Comment: Does Apache have access to **/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dir-name**? You should have an entry for it in your **httpd.conf** file. If not, that’ll be why Apache is saying it’s forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your file permissions, assuming you're on linux, you'd have to do this in the terminal:

```
chown your-user /path/to/directory -R
```

The `-R` is for recursive `chown` which will apply the new settings to all the files and folders in the directory...

After you change the owner, you'll have to right click the folder and set the permissions for *others* to access files.

Comment: Thanks, I did this earlier but forgot to add the -R option. So the folders inside main-dir were restricted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the permissions are not set properly on the directory. Do this:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/dir-name
ls -l
```

Now you should be able to see what user and group own the css directory and what its permissions are. you can use the UNIX / Linux command chown to change the owner of the directory and chmod to change the access mode.